# How can I validate an array of enum values with Nestjs

Tags: nestjs, dto

I feel like a combination of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60505649/forbid-specific-enum-value-for-dto-in-nestjs) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60334856/class-validator-with-array-of-nested-objects-in-nestjs) is what I need to implement, I'm having trouble drawing them together.

I have a DTO that contains an `enum`.

Using Postman, I am sending a `PurchasableType` of `FOO` and expecting to get an error of some sort. Reading through the above links, it seems like the process is quite involved; which makes me thing I'm completely missing the point.

How can I use the validation pipe(s) to make sure only the values in the `purchasable-type.enum.ts` are allowed?

Thank you for any suggestions!

```js
// create-order.dto.ts

import { IsEmail, IsNotEmpty, IsEnum } from 'class-validator';
import { PurchasableType } from '../enum/purchaseable-type.enum';

export class CreateOrderDto {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  readonly userId: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  readonly locationId: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsEnum(PurchasableType)
  readonly purchasableType: PurchasableType;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsEmail()
  readonly email: string;
}
```

```js
// purchasable-type.enum.ts

export enum PurchasableType {
  CLINIC = 'CLINIC',
  EVENT = 'EVENT',
  LESSON = 'LESSON',
  RESERVATION = 'RESERVATION',
  TEAM = 'TEAM',
}
```

**EDIT**

It seems I was also not defining the entity correctly, and that may have been the main issue. I am still curious if my implementation good/bad.

```js
// order.entity.ts

...
import { PurchasableType } from '../enum/purchaseable-type.enum';

@Entity()
export class Order extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

@Column({
    type: 'enum',
    enum: PurchasableType,
  })
```

Now when I send a `purchasableType` of `foo` I am getting a 500 error. If I send any valid value that is within the `enum` I am getting a 200/201.

**EDIT 2**

Sure - here is a bit wider view of what I've got. Everything *seems* to be working properly, I'd just like to have a better grasp of what was really happening.

```
// event.controller.ts

@Post('/:id/orders')
  async purchaseEventTickets(@Body() createOrderDto: CreateOrderDto): 
    Promise<Order> {
    return await this.eventService.purchaseEventTickets(createOrderDto);
  }
```

```
// create-order.dto.ts

export class CreateOrderDto {
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsEnum(PurchasableType)
    readonly purchasableType: PurchasableType;
}
```

```
// event.service.ts

async purchaseEventTickets(createOrderDto: CreateOrderDto): Promise<Order> {
    ...
    return await this.orderRepository.createOrder(createOrderDto);
}
```

```
// order.repository.ts

async createOrder(createOrderDto: CreateOrderDto): Promise<Order> {
    const { purchasableType } = createOrderDto;

    const order = this.create();

    order.purchasableType = purchasableType;

    try {
        await order.save();
    } catch (error) {
        this.logger.error(`Failed to create the order: ${error.stack}`);

        throw new InternalServerErrorException();
    }

    return order;
}
```

Using Postman, if I send an invalid value of "Foo" as a `PurchasableType` I get the expected error.

Comment: could you provide us a bit more info about the way you use the validation pipe ? To me the 500 error seems to be thrown by the ORM, not the validation pipe, which is not what you expect I guess

Comment: Sure! I've updated my question. I hope i've provided a bit more information.
Thank you for your time to help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what your `create-dto` looks like that contains an `enum`.

```
// create-order.dto.ts

import { IsEmail, IsNotEmpty, IsEnum } from 'class-validator';
import { PurchasableType } from '../enum/purchaseable-type.enum';

export class CreateOrderDto {

    ...

    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsEnum(PurchasableType)
    readonly purchasableType: PurchasableType;
}
```

Here is what that enum file looks like:

```
// purchasable-type.enum.ts

export enum PurchasableType {
  CLINIC = 'CLINIC',
  EVENT = 'EVENT',
  LESSON = 'LESSON',
  RESERVATION = 'RESERVATION',
  TEAM = 'TEAM',
}
```

From there I can confidently expect the value of the enum to be one of the above values. If some other value comes through, nest will throw a validation error.

Additionally, If you are attempting to use a nested object (or something with multiple attributes or an array) you can do something like this in your DTO:

```
import { PurchasableType } from '../interface/purchasable-type.interface';
...

@ApiProperty()
@IsArray()
@ArrayMinSize(7)
@ArrayMaxSize(7)
@ValidateNested({ each: true })
@Type(() => PurchasableType)
@IsNotEmpty()
readonly PurchasableType: PurchasableType[];

...
```

Answer (score 26):

It took me a while to find a good solution.

```
@ApiProperty({
  description: 'List of enums',
  isArray: true,
  enum: MyEnum
})
@IsEnum(MyEnum, { each: true })
prop: MyEnum[];
```

Comment: Where is @ApiProperty impoerted from?

Comment: @KaranKumar good questions, that is a swagger(openapi) decorator I use for creating swagger documentation. For this questions is not relevant but it could be useful for those using openapi.

Answer (score 5):

```
  @IsArray()
  @IsEnum(enum, { each: true })
  prop: enum[]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  @IsEnum(myEnum, { each: true })
  @Transform((value) => myEnum[value])
  tags: myEnum[];
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me, I did it this way:

```
@Column({ type: 'enum', enum: MyEnum, array: true })
myProperty: MyEnum[];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enum PARAM_TYPE {
  VENUE_NAME = 'VENUE_NAME',
  USER_NAME = 'USER_NAME',
}
```

---

```
@ApiPropertyOptional({
isArray: true,
 enum: ENUM_TYPE
})
@IsEnum(PARAM_TYPE, { each: true })
params: PARAM_TYPE[];
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?